# asp c# create dynamic pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

My requirement is the ability to create a **pdf file** from a dynamic web-page (`asp / c#`).  I need to have the ability to **adjust the elements position** (in the same way the one could use `@media print` to adjust the styling of the page and I **cannot use anything that needs to be installed client-side**.

Has anyone come across anything which can resolve this dilemma?

Edit: A lot of the solutions I am finding involve initiating code to place every element on the page (`add.paragraph("blah")` for example) but I need something which is more a **snapshot** of the page, but I can **modify the positions of the elements** and then save the pdf.

Comment: Use iTextsharp library.

Comment: I've updated my question to include more information.

Comment: You are the server. You want to create a PDF from what the client is rendering. Not possible.

Comment: Is there nothing that can be done that is similar to @media print.  I could change the positions of the elements and then create a pdf file rather than print the page?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the free (Affero GPL) [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library to be very useful. I have never used it from C# but it claims to be possible.

**Edit: Client side PDF generation**

Since as other commentators have pointed out what you wish to print is located on the client side rather than the server side. Perhaps you should look into JavaScript based PDF libraries. For example (but not limited to) [this](http://jspdf.com/)

Comment: I've updated my question.  Can this achieve what I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

[Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MigraDocOverview.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) One of possibilities.

Comment: I've updated my question.  Can this achieve what I am asking?

Comment: No, and I think this is not possible to achieve what you want.